# Unsure about a step in the analyticity of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, summation, analyticity, cauchy-integral-formula

Consider the following section in a proof in my notes:

We show here that, as a consequence of Cauchy's integral formula
any holomorphic function g(z) in an open domain D is analytic.
Consider a circle centered on $z_0$, within D, and a point z inside the circle.
One can write

$$g(z) = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \oint_C dz' \frac{g(z')}{z'-z} = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \oint dz' \frac{g(z')}{(z'-z_0) - (z-z_0)}$$

and since $|z-z_0| < |z'-z_0| $ one can expand the integrand as

$$g(z) = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \oint dz' \frac{g(z')}{z'-z_0} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{z-z_o}{z' -z_o} \bigg)^n$$

My question is how do we get frost the first line to the second line I am unsure where the summation came from.

Comment: It's a geometric series. Are you, in principle, familiar with those?

Comment: Yes I am familiar wit them but still unsure where this comes from?

Comment: Then work backwards from the second equation by plugging in the geometric series. Where do you get stuck?